# How to integrate NetScalar login in cordova hybrid mobile app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, authentication

I have cordova mobile app, Now I want to integrate Netscalar login for secure login authentication. suggest me how to open third party gate-way login page through mobile and and after successful authentication how to return control back to app.

Answer (score 0):

For net-scalar login I have open net-scalar url in inAppBrowser. For that you have to install plugin of inAppBrowser

```
var authPage = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank','location=no,clearsessioncache=yes');
authPage.addEventListener("loadstop", function () {
    authPage.executeScript (
        { code: //your code here }, 
       function( values ) {
           //play with values
           authPage.close(); //close your browser after successfully authentication.
       }
    )
});
```